# c++ rabbitmq how to send a byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, rabbitmq

I'm using the [C++ RabbitMQ client](https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient). The code below shows how to send a string.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Setup stuff

    string a="hello world";
    boost::shared_ptr<SimplePublisher> pub=SimplePublisher::Create(channel, "wt");

    pub->Publish(a);
}
```

Here are the `Publish()` methods:

```
#include "SimplePublisher.h"

void SimplePublisher::Publish(const std::string &message)
{
    BasicMessage::ptr_t outgoing_message = 

    BasicMessage::Create(message);
    outgoing_message->Body(message);

    Publish(outgoing_message);
}

void SimplePublisher::Publish(const BasicMessage::ptr_t message)
{
    m_channel->BasicPublish(m_publisherExchange, "", message);
}
```

The `Publish()` method call 1 of 3 `Create()` methods in the `BasicMessage` class as shown here. The hello world example calls the one with a string argument `Create(const std::string &body)`.

```
  /**
    * Create a new empty BasicMessage object
    */
  static ptr_t Create() { return boost::make_shared<BasicMessage>(); }

  /**
    * Create a new BasicMessage object
    * Creates a new BasicMessage object with a given body
    * @param body the message body.
    * @returns a new BasicMessage object
    */
  static ptr_t Create(const std::string &body) {
    return boost::make_shared<BasicMessage>(body);
  }

  /**
    * Create a new BasicMessage object
    * Creates a new BasicMessage object with a given body, properties
    * @param body the message body. The message body is NOT duplicated.
    * Passed in message body is deallocated when: body is set or message is
    * destructed.
    * @properties the amqp_basic_properties_t struct. Note this makes a deep
    * copy of the properties struct
    * @returns a new BasicMessage object
    */
  static ptr_t Create(amqp_bytes_t_ &body,
                      amqp_basic_properties_t_ *properties) {
    return boost::make_shared<BasicMessage>(body, properties);
  }
```

My question is that, I want to send a byte array and not a string. Therefore, I need to call `Create(amqp_bytes_t_ &body, amqp_basic_properties_t_ *properties)`.

The library is a wrapper around the [RabbitMQ C AMQP](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c). `amqp_bytes_t_` and `amqp_basic_properties_t_` are structs in that library.

Could anybody demonstrate how to send a byte array in this example instead of hello world?

Comment: `string` in C++ is a byte array (that can also be used to hold some strings, with some caveats). What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Cubic I have an image (jpeg) stored in a file that I want to open and write to a RabbitMQ queue. Can I read an image into a string and send that? This post [link#(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274046/using-c-to-write-an-image-to-a-rabbitmq-queue/50275102?noredirect=1#comment87567686_50275102) suggests that there is a " a property to set the body as a byte array directly (no conversion required)". This makes me think I have to call `Create(amqp_bytes_t_ &body, amqp_basic_properties_t_ *properties)`. What do you think?